# Is Collections.emptyList() a drop-in replacement for Collections.EMPTY_LIST?

Tags: java, collections

Can I safely find and replace all `Collections.EMPTY_LIST` with `Collections.emptyList()`, or is there a chance of breaking things by doing this?  Same question for `Collections.EMPTY_SET` and `Collections.EMPTY_MAP`.

The project I'm working on is using Java 8.

Comment: Which version of Java?

Comment: I'm using Java 8 - edited the main question to address this.

Comment: High chance there exists some code that would break, low chance you'll run into it.

Answer (score 3):

In principle yes, you can use the method wherever you used the constant, but bear in mind - the method is generic and won't raise a warning, whereas using the constant will raise a "raw type" warning in some Java versions (but not in Java 8, mind you). For completeness' sake, here's the code - notice the annotations used to eliminate the warnings:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static final List EMPTY_LIST = new EmptyList<>();

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static final <T> List<T> emptyList() {
    return (List<T>) EMPTY_LIST;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code of [`Collections`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.emptyList%28%29), you see that `emptyList()` is just a generic wrapper around `EMPTY_LIST`, so the answer is yes.

```
public static final <T> List<T> emptyList() {
    return (List<T>) EMPTY_LIST;
}
```

The implementations of `emptyMap()` and `emptySet()` are using the same structure.

Comment: Why does the fact that it's a wrapper imply that it works as a drop-in replacement?

Answer (score 1):

Collections.EMPTY_LIST is an immutable list but not type-safe. Where as
Collections.emptyList() is immutable and type-safe. Collections.emptyList() would be the preferred usage.